# Ionic 4 RouterLink not working after logout/login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing

I'm having an interesting bug while developing an ionic 4 app. 
When i log out of my application and log in again, the routerLinks aren't working anymore.

The routerLinks are set on a card. They are working fine until i'm logging out and in again. No errors and the Browser Url is changing correctly, but nothing happens.

I know this problem is similar tot this one: [ionic 4 + angular: routerLink only works first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859509/ionic-4-angular-routerlink-only-works-first-time) and i tried the provided solutions but they didn't work..

`npm i @ionic/angular` didn't work.

Providing a click listener on the cards didn't work either:

```js
openPage(page: string) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url + '/' + page);
}
```

My Card:

```
<ion-card routerLink="/developers/home/apps">
   ...
</ion-card>
```

My Login Method:

```
login() {
    const token = this.databaseService.getToken();

    if (token) {
      this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, token).then(() => {
        this.authenticationState.next(true);
      });
    }
}
```

My Logout Method:

```
logout() {
    return this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY).then(() => {
      this.authenticationState.next(false);
    });
}
```

After i log in again my Application routes me correctly to the home page with the card view. But after that i'm stuck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: apply click listeners on the card and navigate using the following code: `this.router.navigate(["/page-name"]);`

Comment: Tried it, didn't work..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
To solve it I used `replaceUrl: true`:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { replaceUrl: true });
```